# Use Windows 10 PC as a Postscript print server for Mac users on Network

Tags: windows, networking, mac, printer, postscript

This one seems very difficult to get my head around. We've just obtained a Sharp MX-2600N printer copier which is a very capable printer. This printer works very well with Windows users on my network but not Mac users. Apparently you need to purchase a Postscript module from Sharp (at exorbitant cost) just to allow printer use for Mac users.

I got to thinking maybe I could setup a Windows PC to act like a basic print server so Mac users could send print jobs to the PC and that takes care of all the processing rather than buying a Postscript module for what is at most 3 users on my network.

My questions;

(A) Is this doable? (B) Is this doable on Windows 10? (C) Am I onto a looser by even thinking along the lines of using a PC as a print server? (D) How?

Thanks in advance all, Phill

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, but note that I have not tried it.

Use [GSPRINT](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsprint.htm) (part of [GSview](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/), the graphical interface for [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)) on a WIndows PC/server. This is a free utility to print PostScript and PDF files to any printer. The following command sends a file to a printer:

GSVIEW -printer "Printer_name" "filename"

To make it work in your case, first set up the Mac to print to a file in a shared Windows directory. As far as I know, OSX cannot "print to file", but if you [print to PDF](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-print-to-pdf-in-mac-os-x/) it will create a PDF file. Create that file in the shared folder. On the PC, set up a batch file that does the following:

- Check for presence of a file in the directory
- Run GSPRINT to print the file
- Delete the file
- Wait a suitable time and loop to the beginning

Once that is set up, any file created in the shared folder will be sent to whichever printer you nominate.

To use GSVIEW, GhostScript and GSVIEW need to be installed.

Comment: Right, I think the main problem I'm having is getting the Mac to talk to the PC. Basic sharing of the printer on the network doesn't seem to want to work properly and it remains invisible to any Mac on the network even if you try and find it by IP address. I'm thinking I may need to approach this whole thing in a different way - I was reading this article [here](http://www.kentoyer.com/2012/09/14/mac-printing-to-a-non-postscript-printer/) which seems to offer some hope except that even though the writer of has the same printer as me, it doesn't appear in the Ghostscript/ Foomatic list.

Comment: Foomatic is used to convert the PS file to printer code. "the main problem I'm having is getting the Mac to talk to the PC". Create a PS printer file on the Mac and take that to the PC (via the network or even a USB drive, for now). Then use GSPRINT to print it.